# prevent multiple button pressing

Tags: javascript

I have a simple countdown that is activated by a button. Using `onclick` i start the action, but I noticed that if you keep pressing the button it increases the time and the countdown is out of sync. How would I go about preventing this from happening, and only allowing one click at a time?

```
  var count = 10,
      startcounter = document.getElementById("stercount");

startcounter.onclick = function() {
  countdown = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = count + " seconds remaining!";
    if (count <= 0) {
      clearInterval(countdown);
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Done!";
    }
    count--;
  }, 1000);
};
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/StWXk/1/
​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the click handler:

```
startcounter.onclick = function() {
    this.onclick = null;
    ...
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/StWXk/3/

**Edit:** Based on your pause button requirement, you can re-bind the click handler when the timer is paused:

```
function startTimer() {
    this.onclick = null;
    ...
}

startcounter.onclick = startTimer;

pausecounter.onclick = function() {
    startcounter.onclick = startTimer;
    clearTimeout(countdown);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/StWXk/8/

Comment: i notice if i add a stop and pause the start no longer works. see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/StWXk/7/

Comment: @mr10 - Name your function and re-bind the click handler when the timer is paused.

Answer (score 4):

Set a flag variable `isClicked` default as `false`. When you click on the button, set `isClicked` to `true`. During `click` event, if `isClicked` is `true` then make it `return false`.

```
var isClicked = false;  
var count = 10,
      startcounter = document.getElementById("stercount");

startcounter.onclick = function() {
    if(isClicked) return false;

    isClicked = true;
    countdown = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = count + " seconds remaining!";
    if (count <= 0) {
      clearInterval(countdown);
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Done!";
    }
    count--;
  }, 1000);
};​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/StWXk/2/

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to this, one is defining and setting a flag to keep track of the timer is running outside of the onclick, the other is calling clearInterval before the countdown to stop any already running countdowns.

Solution 1:
*A flag to indicate if the timer is running or not.*

```
var count = 10,
    startcounter = document.getElementById("stercount"),
    running;

startcounter.onclick = function() {
    if (running)
        return;

    running = true;
    countdown = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = count + " seconds remaining!";
        if (count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(countdown);
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Done!";
        }
        count--;
    }, 1000);
};
```

Solution 2:
*Stopping the timer with `clearInterval` before starting it.*

```
var count = 10,
    startcounter = document.getElementById("stercount");

startcounter.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(countdown);
    countdown = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = count + " seconds remaining!";
        if (count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(countdown);
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Done!";
        }
        count--;
    }, 1000);
};
```

Solution 3:
*You can use `countdown` as your flag, but when doing so you must make sure to set it to null every time you clear it. This is basically the same as solution 1 except for dropping that one var.*

**Edit:** This might not actually work if you don't define `countdown` in your vars list above the onclick since your countdown-DIV will populate the countdown-global.

```
var count = 10,
    startcounter = document.getElementById("stercount");

startcounter.onclick = function() {
    if (countdown)
        return;

    countdown = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = count + " seconds remaining!";
        if (count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(countdown);
            countdown = null;
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Done!";
        }
        count--;
    }, 1000);
};
```

ps. Did you forget to define countdown in the vars at the top of the code or is countdown defined elsewhere? Right now it will be a global and any other piece of code (e.g. a library) could overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is pretty easy using .ONE, after timeout (2seconds) bind .ONE() again to button

```
<script>
            var execute_form_func = function(){
                console.log("Click on button");
                //some code or other stuff
                ....
                // bind same function to button
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    console.log("Enabling"); 
                    $( "#update_submit" ).one("click",execute_form_func); 
                }, 2000);

            };
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $( "#update_submit" ).one("click",execute_form_func);
            });
</script>
```